# How to create an array of objects with different instances?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a java app which has the following classes: `Car` and `Phone`. Each class has the method `connectToBluetooth()`, which prints a message regarding the class' connection to bluetooth.

In another class, I want to create an array of objects in which I add the instances of each one of the objects already created. Then, I want to access the `connectToBluetooth` method coresponding to each instance. I have created one instance for each class:

I want to create an array of these two instances and to access the `connectToBluetooth` method coresponding to each class. (The constructors ask for the owner and the device's color )

```
    Car car = new Car("John", "red");
    car.connectToBluetooth();

    Phone phone = new Phone("Susan","black");
    phone.connectToBluetooth();
```

Comment: Please post what you tried so far

Comment: i guess that the thing you need is to define a common interface for both kind of classes an itetare against an array of those interfaces invoking the connect to BlueTooth. Teel me if that gives you an idea

Comment: @Victor, I have already created an interface, and in both classes I have implemented that interface.

Comment: that's ok luli, that would be a second step (first is defing the interface, second is to implement it). Now in a thirdh step you have to use it. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: @Victor, I have posted the solution, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure, that your design mixing different classes in one array is a good design? IMHO, it'd be better to come up with a design where you don't mix those entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual solution, where Bluetooth is the interface implemented:

```
Bluetooth[] bluetooth= new Bluetooth[2];
bluetooth[0] = new Car("John", "blue"); 
bluetooth[0].connectToBluetooth(); //-> prints message coresponding to Car class 
bluetooth[1] = new Phone("Susan", "black");
bluetooth[1].connectToBluetooth(); //-> prints message coresponding to Phone class
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Object[] arr = new Object[]

You could use array of `Object`, but in this case you have to case concrete instance before invoke `connectToBluetooth()`:

```
Object[] arr = { new Car("John", "red"), new Phone("Susan","black") };

for (Object obj : arr) {
    if (obj instance of Car)
        ((Car)obj).connectToBluetooth();
    else if (obj instance of Phone)
        ((Phone)obj).connectToBluetooth();
}
```

---

#### Bluetooth[] arr = new Bluetooth[]

More correct way is to declare an interace with `connectToBluetooth()` method and use it as array type:

```
interface Bluetooth {
    void connectToBluetooth();
}

class Car implements Bluetooth {} 
class Phone implements Bluetooth {}

Bluetooth[] arr = { new Car("John", "red"), new Phone("Susan","black") };

for (Bluetooth bluetooth : arr)
    bluetooth.connectToBluetooth();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `Objects` for where you can add both `Object` types to it which is not a good way. The better way is to create a super type for `Phone` and `Car` and create a array of that Type (super type can be an interface or a class).

For an example create a `class` called `BlueToothDevice` and extend that class to both Phone and Car. Then create an array of `BlueToothDevice` type and add both of them.

Comment: Yes, You got it :)

Comment: If `BlueToothDevice` will never be instantiated then I would rather create an Interface

Comment: True. An Interface would be better. Just took it as an example to explain him and I have mentioned super type can be an interface or a class.